# Generic inheritance constraint on class parameter fails

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

```
public class Test<T>
{
    private T something;
    public Test<NewT> Cast<NewT>() where T : NewT
    {
        return new Test<NewT>() { something = this.something };
    }
}
```

VS Error: 'Test.Cast()' does not define type parameter 'T'

Why does this happens?

Comment: You cannot have a *method* impose a constraint on a generic parameter for the *type*. If you want to constrain `T`, you have to impose that constraint at the type level.

Comment: The `where T : NewT` should be at the class definition, not at the method definition.

Comment: I want to constraint NewT must be a Parent of T but it is not possible as I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you can only constrain type parameters that are defined in the method. `T` is not defined in the method, but in the class, so you can't constrain  it like that.

You can, however, make `Cast` an extension method:

```
// in some static class
public static Test<NewT> Cast<T, NewT>(this Test<T> test) where T : NewT {
    return new Test<NewT>() { something = test.something }; 
}
```

This means that `something` has to be made public, which can sometimes be undesirable. You can alternatively do something like this:

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public T Something { get; private set; }

    public Test(T something) {
        Something = something;
    }

}

// in some static class
public static Test<NewT> Cast<T, NewT>(this Test<T> test) where T : NewT
{
    return new Test<NewT>(test.Something);
}
```

Comment: I concluded that the c # syntax does not allow you to create the following constraint: "The type must be a parent of SOMETHING ". There is only a restriction for childs

Comment: You can _kind of_ do that with interfaces and delegates (it's called contravariance), but not classes. Did the workaround work for you? If it did, consider accepting this answer by clicking on that checkmark. @AndrewVinichenko